# Configuring memcached with PHP

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I have a web application which queries opentsdb server(which in backend using Hbase cluster) for the datapoints of different metrics and using dygraph javascript graphing library, I am plotting those metrics. Since getting all the datapoints of past one day from opentsdb for a particular metric is itself taking nearly 2 seconds, my application which is plotting nearly 25 metrics is becoming very slow.

In order to reduce this latency, I am thinking of using memcached module of php5 for caching all the queries. But I have few questions regarding memcached.

- Is there any way I can configure memcache to keep on updating its cache in the background by running some command line queries after particular interval of time.
- Is there any way I can configure memcache to always reply for a query using cache instead of first updating its cache because my application just plots datapoints for past one day. Missing out some data-points is not that critical.

Please suggest me in case there is any other to reduce this latency also.

Answer (score 2):

Neither one is job of memcached. Your application should update the cache in background (by running cron) and you can set the cache to expire in (lets say 12 hours) but check the time (you have to store it in the cache) and if there is less then 2 hours to expiration, run background process to update the cache

Comment: thank you for ur reply, whether running the command which queries for datapoints for a metric in the memcached server as cronjob will update the cache.